# Каким образом массивы через данный цикл сливаются в один

Tags: javascript

```
for(let i = 0; i < (arr1.length + arr2.length); i++) {

    if(i < arr1.length) {
    
    arr3.push(arr1[i])
    } else {
     arr3.push(arr2[i - arr1.length])
    }
    
}

console.log(arr3)
```

Каков принцип работы данного кода. Никак не могу понять каким образом массивы через данный цикл сливаются в один?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При объединении известна конечная длина массива: `arr1.length + arr2.length`

Далее в цикле в результирующий массив добавляются по одному сначала элементы из первого массива:

```
if(i < arr1.length) { // при этом условии
    arr3.push(arr1[i]) // `i` соответствует индексу элементы в массиве `arr1`
}
```

затем из второго

```
else { // в эту ветвь попадаем, когда все элементы из первого массива добавлены в результат
    arr3.push(arr2[i - arr1.length]) // в этом случае чтобы получить индекс элемента из второго массива, нужно из `i` вычесть длину первого массива
}
```

Если записать это двумя циклами будет намного понятнее:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr3.push(arr1[i])
}
for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    arr3.push(arr2[i])
}
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: Не особо понятно условие. То есть выполняется If и записывается в arr3, затем перемещаемся в else и тут происходит соединения двух массивов?

Comment: @egor, нет, сначала ты попадаешь только в `if` - как будто бежишь в цикле по первому массиву и каждый элемент добавляешь в `arr3`, потом попадаешь только в `else`, как будто бежишь в цикле по второму массиву и снова по одному элементу добавляешь в `arr3`

Comment: @egor, пример с двумя циклами в ответе показывает наглядно что происходит

Comment: спасибо, наконец-то усвоил